Metabase and PostGIS
I'm using metabase to explore a large postgis database. Metabase has a map viewer but from what I understand I can only make specific map types. One of my tables has a geomtry column with WKT data. Is there a way to plot those WKT polygons in a metabase dashboard?

From what I read, Metabase only supports point data (as lat,lon pairs). You don't provide any information about your data but, typically, your task should be to convert your wkt points to XY pairs (using, e.g. st_x(geom), st_y(geom)). If your data represents polygons, you can use st_centroid(geom) or st_pointonsurface(geom) to switch to point data.
In any case, your coordinates must be of a non-planar projection (e.g. WGS84).

Thanks. I have polygons and I wanted to see the actual areas. I'll adapt to use the polygon centroid.
